# Derive the maximum likelihood estimators of  and 

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, cumulative-distribution-functions

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvh0T.png)Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, Pareto-distributed, with cumulative distributions given by
$$Fx(;\lambda)=1 −1/x^\lambda$$
$$Fy(y;\lambda)=1 −1/x^\mu$$

with $x, y\ge 1$ and $\lambda, \mu > 0$. Let $Z = \min\{X, Y\}$ and define the (non)censoring indicator

$$\delta =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }X < Y,\\ 0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

How do we Derive the maximum likelihood estimators of $\theta$ and $p$? What function do we create?

Let $Z_1$, ... , $Z_n$ be a random sample from $fZ(z; \theta)$, with $\theta =\lambda + \mu$, and let $\delta_1$, ... , $\delta_n$ be a random sample from $fδ(d; p)$, with $p = \lambda/(\lambda + \mu)$.

I found the frequency function for $\delta$ but I am not sure how to get the density function for $Z$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A picture in these types of problems is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson added picture.

Answer (score 1):

As you found the pmf of $\delta$, I will show how to derive the pdf of $Z$.

\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= P(Z \leq z) \\
       &= P(min(X, Y) \leq z) \\
       &= 1 - P(min(X, Y) > z) \\
       &= 1 - P(X > z, Y > z) \\
       &= 1 - P(X > z)P(Y > z) \\
       &= 1 - (1-P(X \leq z))(1 - P(Y \leq z)) \\
       &= 1 - (1-F_X(z))(1-F_Y(z)) \\
       &= F_X(z) + F_Y(z) - F_X(z)F_Y(z) \\
\end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \frac{d}{dz}\{F_X(z) + F_Y(z) - F_X(z)F_Y(z)\} \\
       &= f_X(z) + f_Y(z) - f_X(z)F_Y(z) - F_X(z)f_Y(z) \\
\end{align}

We can easily get $f_X(x), f_Y(y)$.

- $f_X(x) = \lambda x^{-\lambda-1}$
- $f_Y(y) = \mu y^{-\mu-1}$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= f_X(z) + f_Y(z) - f_X(z)F_Y(z) - F_X(z)f_Y(z) \\
       &= \lambda z^{-\lambda-1} + \mu z^{-\mu-1} - \lambda z^{-\lambda-1}(1 - z^{-\mu}) - (1 - z^{-\lambda})\mu z^{-\mu-1} \\
       &= \lambda z^{-\lambda-1} + \mu z^{-\mu-1} - \lambda z^{-\lambda-1} - \mu z^{-\mu-1} + (\lambda + \mu)z^{-(\lambda+\mu+1)} \\
       &= (\lambda + \mu)z^{-(\lambda+\mu+1)} \\
       &= \theta z^{-(\theta+1)}
\end{align}

Now, you can get the MLE from it.

(I got $\displaystyle \frac{n}{log(\sum z_i)}$. I guess you can make it to the answer.)

---

I got the pmf of $\delta$ as below.

- $P(\delta = 1) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} = p$
- $P(\delta = 0) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} = 1-p$

Comment: thank you very much for the help.

Was your PMF of   /+ ? Also, to find the MLE did you form the equation       
(−(+1))^di*(1-/+)^1-di? 
Moreover, your answer /(∑) is derivative w.r.t to theta?

Comment: @User-3.141 Hi, I haven't got the pmf of $\delta$. After solving it, I will edit the answer. Yes, it is MLE for $\theta$.

Comment: @User-3.141 I added the pmf of $\delta$.